# Toggle switch control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, toggleswitch

I am designing a *toggle switch* control using `CheckBox`, but currently my control only draws a circle. How can I draw round shapes like the below image and how can I change the location of the circle based on the value of the control to represent checked and unchecked states like the below image?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class MyCheckBox:CheckBox
{
    public MyCheckBox()
    {
        this.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        this.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
        this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPaintBackground(e);
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var c = e.Graphics.ClipBounds;
            var r = this.ClientRectangle;
            r.Inflate(-FlatAppearance.BorderSize, -FlatAppearance.BorderSize);
            path.AddEllipse(r);
            e.Graphics.SetClip(path);
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.SetClip(c);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            if (this.Checked)
            {
                using (var p = new Pen(FlatAppearance.BorderColor,
                                       FlatAppearance.BorderSize))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p, r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @SurvivalMachine, why u are downvoting my question.if u have any doubt,just let me know.

Comment: "Where is the error in my code?" <-- It would be nice to get more information like how it's broken now and where do you think the error could be.

Comment: The question now contains enough information with a clear problem statement and codes. The question and the answer is a good example for WinForms developers to show how they can customize rendering of a check box to have such appearance. Now the question is more clear. I believe it can be reopened even voted. This way, both question and answer will be more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know this is a Windows Forms question. But you may want to take a look at [Toggle Switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/toggles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or read more about [Universal Windows App Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/index?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Anyway, here is an answer for Windows Forms developers. It shows how we can customize rendering of a checkbox to have such appearance.

Currently you are drawing only an ellipse, and it's quite a toggle button. But if you want to show it like the below image, you should first draw a round shape for background, and then based on the `Checked` value, draw the check circle. Using the code in *Example* part of the answer you can have a [`CheckBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) with such a UI:

[image]

**Example**

The important thing about this sample is it's completely a `CheckBox` control and supports check using mouse and keyboard. It also supports data-binding and all other standard features of `CheckBox`. The code is not perfect, but it is a good start point to have a yes/no toggle switch:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public MyCheckBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        Padding = new Padding(6);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnPaintBackground(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        using (var path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            var d = Padding.All;
            var r = this.Height - 2 * d;
            path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180);
            path.AddArc(this.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180);
            path.CloseFigure();
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Checked ? Brushes.DarkGray : Brushes.LightGray, path);
            r = Height - 1;
            var rect = Checked ? new Rectangle(Width - r - 1, 0, r, r)
                               : new Rectangle(0, 0, r, r);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Checked ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.WhiteSmoke, rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the height and width here?

Comment: @Aousafrashid By setting `AutoSize` to `false` and changing the size at design-time.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Can we made this toggle checkbox Vertical instead of horizontal