# Group toggle buttons in vb.net winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I'm working on a theme for a little app where I need to place some toggle buttons.
Like showed in many place this site, I've done it using a checkbox and changing the apparance by a custom onpaint event ,(basically a draw it like a button). Then I realize that checkbox not grouping like radio buttons, so I've done the same with a radio buttons, but even if I place 2 of them in a groupbox, I still can "checked" them both;
which is the best way to do that?
here sample code that I used to make some test:

```
Class MyToggleButton
Inherits ThemeControl154
Private _Checked As Boolean
Private X As Integer



Public Property Checked As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Checked
    End Get
    Set(ByVal V As Boolean)
        _Checked = V
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property


Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnClick(e)
    _Checked = Not _Checked
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub ColorHook()
    SetColor("Border", Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 200, 200))
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub PaintHook()
    Dim Border As Color
    Border = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(160, GetColor("Border"))
    G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
    G.Clear(Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 60, 60, 60))

    Dim LGBNone As LinearGradientBrush
    Dim LGBOver As LinearGradientBrush
    Dim LGBDown As LinearGradientBrush

    If Checked Then ' use Blue-ish color
        LGBNone = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 255), Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 50, 255))
        LGBOver = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 255), Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 40, 255))
        LGBDown = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 255), Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 30, 255))
    Else ' use default colors
        LGBNone = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 65, 65), Color.FromArgb(255, 50, 50, 50))
        LGBOver = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 65, 65), Color.FromArgb(255, 40, 40, 40))
        LGBDown = New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(0, Height - 1), Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 65, 65), Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 30, 30))
    End If

    Dim Polygon() As Point
    Dim Polygon2() As Point
    Polygon = New Point() {New Point(0, 0), New Point(Width - 1, 0), New Point(Width - 1, Height - 7), New Point(Width - 2, Height - 6), New Point(Width - 3, Height - 5), New Point(Width - 4, Height - 4), New Point(Width - 5, Height - 3), New Point(Width - 6, Height - 2), New Point(Width - 7, Height - 1), New Point(0, Height - 1)}
    Polygon2 = New Point() {New Point(1, 1), New Point(Width - 2, 1), New Point(Width - 2, Height - 7), New Point(Width - 8, Height - 2), New Point(1, Height - 2)}
    Select Case State
        Case MouseState.Down
            G.FillPolygon(LGBDown, Polygon)
        Case MouseState.None
            G.FillPolygon(LGBNone, Polygon)
        Case MouseState.Over
            G.FillPolygon(LGBOver, Polygon)
    End Select
    G.DrawPolygon(Pens.Black, Polygon)
    G.DrawPolygon(New Pen(Border), Polygon2)
    DrawText(New SolidBrush(GetColor("Border")), HorizontalAlignment.Center, -2, 0)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: That's not the normal behavior of a RadioButton. So, it must be something with your code (which you didn't include). Anyway, I think you'll like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38432140/8967612). The code is in C# but can be easily translated (or compiled into a DLL as is).

Comment: As long as the `RadioButton`s belong to the same parent, then they will automatically toggle. If each `RadioButton` has a different parent then it won't toggle.

Comment: Note, however, that toggle switches usually substitute CheckBoxes, not RadioButtons. So, having a toggle affects the state of others might be an unexpected behavior to the user. What's exactly do you not like about the universally recognized RadioButton?

Comment: basically Radiobuttons work for my goal but I prefer button apparance.

Comment: @Damien Did you try the `RadioButton.Appearance` property? E.g., `RadioButton1.Appearance = Appearance.Button`.

Comment: Tried, and work, but lose the customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can imitate the behavior of a group of RadioButton controls in a container. Just find the controls of the same type in the `Parent.Controls` collection and uncheck them when the current instance is checked.

**Example**

Add this method to `MyToggleButton` class.

```vb
Private Sub InvalidateControls()
    If Not IsHandleCreated OrElse Not Checked Then Return

    For Each c In Parent.Controls.OfType(Of MyToggleButton)
        If c IsNot Me AndAlso c.Checked Then
            c.Checked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Call the method from the setter of the `Checked` property:

```vb
Private _Checked As Boolean

Public Property Checked As Boolean
    Get
        Return _Checked
    End Get
    Set(ByVal V As Boolean)
        _Checked = V
        InvalidateControls()
        Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

In the `OnClick` method, you shouldn't toggle the `Checked` property, its a `RadioButton` not a `CheckBox`. You should:

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnClick(e)

    ' Set the property not the variable to call the 
    ' setter's methods.
    If Not Checked Then Checked = True
End Sub
```

Also, it's important to dispose of the graphics objects when you finish drawing. You should call `LGBNone.Dispose()`, `LGBDown.Dispose()`, and `LGBOver.Dispose()` at the end of the `PaintHook` method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks.